# Multiple splitview controller with tabbar controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I have five views in tab bar & clicking on each item of tab bar one view controller will open.
My view's hierarchy is like
window-->uiviewcontroller-->uitabbar controller
Among them two of the tab bar contains splitview controller.
So here i have to generate two different splitview controller & i know that i can add splitview from window but how can i generate more than one split view controller?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @RKK i have tried by adding uisplitview controller to particlar view & after add subview into that but this doesn't works for me..